# Parse query error on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

When i run this code on device iOS 9 it's working but if i use device iOS 7

the parse query return that error " NSError *   domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840 "

How Can i fix this problem ?

```
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        [self.tableView reloadData];


    } else {

        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        NSNumber *errorNumber = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"code"];
        NSString *errorMsg;
        switch ([errorNumber intValue]) {
            case 100:{
                errorMsg=@"The Internet connection appears to be offline";

            }

                break;

            default:
                errorMsg=@"Oops! Something went wrong.";

                break;
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

When i used parse 1.8.5 it solved my problem